# Shorter syntax for List construction

Tags: c#, static-methods, c#-6.0

With C# 6.0, given this static method:

```
public static List<T> List<T>(params T[] items) => new List<T>(items);
```

and an appropriate `using`:

```
using static ListTest.ListUtils;
```

I can use `List` to construct lists:

```
var lsInt = List(10, 20, 30);

var lsStr = List("abc", "bcd", "cde");
```

Without the `List` method, construction can be done via:

```
var lsIntInitializer = new List<int>() { 10, 20, 30 };
```

The name `List` is now being used for both a class and a method. It seems to work fine, but besides not being considered idiomatic, are there any technical reasons why I shouldn't use `List` as the method name here?

I can also use `list`, however that's not idiomatic in a different way, in that methods tend to be capitalized.

Note, I have no problems with going a non-idiomatic route, but if there's an accepted practice in this area, I'd like to know about it.

Of course, C# 6.0 with its `using static` is a brave new world, so perhaps there's simply not yet enough community experience around this sort of thing.

The [language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) project uses a similar approach to construct `ImmutableList` objects. In that case, they use the name `list`.

An entire working example from which the above excerpts were taken is shown below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using static ListTest.ListUtils;

namespace ListTest
{
    public static class ListUtils
    {
        public static List<T> List<T>(params T[] items) => new List<T>(items);
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lsInt = List(10, 20, 30);

            var lsStr = List("abc", "bcd", "cde");

            var lsIntInitializer = new List<int>() { 10, 20, 30 };

            lsInt.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

            lsStr.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No technical reasons that I know of, but why not choose something more appropriate and less confusing like `MakeList`?

Comment: @DStanley Yup, I was also considering `MakeList`.

Comment: Also note that _shorter_ code isn't always _better_ code.

Comment: The most important objective of code is to correctly perform the job it was designed for.  The second most important objective of code is to be easy for the next guy to understand.

Comment: I'd start looking at the non-idiomatic variable names first, personally :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yup, that's the approach the [language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) project took. They went with `list`.

Comment: @dharmatech: I was referring to the underscores...

Comment: @JonSkeet Updated just for you Jon. ;-)

Comment: While smth makes your code more readable and semantic, there is nothing wrong with non-idiomatic naming. What's a meaning of conventions, if they are just adding noise.

It's an opinion, but List(1, 2, 3) looks fine and readable. Asked for a list - got it.

Comment: @Vladislav To me, method names should be verbs. If `List` is a verb, then it isn't going to *create* a list, nor are you asking to return a list, but it's going to perform the act of listing--such as putting the numbers into some location (and with a `void` return type). So no agreement, here.

Comment: @ErikE it can be treated just like a constructor shorter notation.

(Looks fine for me, because FSharp has similar feature - constructors can be invoked like simple functions, `new` is optional)

Comment: @Vladislav But this is C# and it is idiomatic, importantly so, for methods to be verbs. Using a noun as a verb is going to confuse the million C# programmers out there.

Comment: @ErikE million of C# programmers will be confused by C#6 itself :)
Language is changing, conventions should as well.

It's just an opinion and I have no real arguments to convince, so

Comment: @ErikE  And of course, I'm not suggesting to use nouns for usual methods naming, they must be verbs. But in that concrete case, noun and type inference are playing well together.

Comment: @ErikE By the way, what will you say about such a [thing](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RYzGVA)? Not the best implementation, but idea should be clear.

Comment: @Vladislav It does make for some nice syntax, but there's nothing that would stop you from calling the method `MakeNode` instead of `Node`. I think your tree could be improved by not having non-leaf and leaf nodes--all of them could contain data as well as children, and you know whether something is a leaf node by whether it has children or not.

Comment: @ErikE Tree is not a point here, just example made on the knee to show all the power of new DSL possibilities. The last thing I wanted to add :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a less confusing approach would be this:

```
public static class List
{
    public static List<T> Create<T>(params T[] items) => new List<T>(items);
}
```

Which you would call like this:

```
var lsInt = List.Create(10, 20, 30);
```

(without `using static` of course; importing a class with a method named `Create` would be *really* confusing)

This is the same approach used by the immutable collections (`ImmutableList`, `ImmutableArray`, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Author of Language-Ext here.  So obviously you know my opinion on this.  I now use `List` rather than `list` to construct a `Lst<T>` which is a wrapper for `ImmutableList<T>`.

I think the problem with C#'s idioms is they're firmly rooted in the Java/C# 1 era.  Which is fine, if that's the style of coding you want.  I think you can argue that C# is becoming more and more like Scala and less and less like Java, so if you're going to grasp the newer functional tools in C# then perhaps moving your idioms closer to Scala (or F#) makes sense.

I see one of the comments from @ErikE often in these types of discussions:

> To me, method names should be verbs. If List is a verb, then it isn't going to create a list, nor are you asking to return a list, but it's going to perform the act of listing--such as putting the numbers into some location (and with a void return type). So no agreement, here

This 'method names should be verbs' thing needs to die, along with the obsession with anything the Gang of Four have written.  It's just one style, one technique.  You don't look at list construction in F# for example (below) and think "I can't possibly comprehend what that's doing because there's no verbs"

```
let values = [1;2;3;4;5]
```

It is clearly constructing a list.  How about in C#

```
var values = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

'new', new what?  It's obvious that using the name `List` as a constructor is as descriptive, if not more so that the language's own built in construction of lists (arrays in this case, but the point is still valid).

I have unified a style for Language-Ext now, and that is:

- Static constructor functions (like `List`) start with a capital letter and either describe the type or the state the type will be in post-construction (so for `Option<T>` you construct with `Some(value)` or `None`).
- Static classes that are like modules in F# use camelCase naming, for example: `List.map`, `List.filter`, `Set.intersect` etc.
- Methods are PascalCase in the usual way.

This kind of gives the best of both worlds, you get `List.filter(...)` for the functional programmers that want their code to look like other functional languages, and you get fluent methods `list.Filter(...)` for those that find the style 'challenging'

The most important thing is your code means something to you and your team.  Dogma should rarely be the reason for choosing a style.